# Problema com codificações diferentes entre bancos de dados

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, utf-8

Estou criando uma aplicação que preciso pegar alguns dados que estão em um banco SQL Server com codificação iso-8859-1, e inserir em um banco MySQL com codificação utf-8.

Algumas palavras com acentos estão dando erro ao inserir no banco MySQL.

```
Incorrect string value: '\xC7AFR\xC3O' for column 'produto' at row 1
```

A palavra que aparece com erro é Açafrão. Como posso contornar este erro e inserir o registro no banco?

obs: estou usando PHP

Comment: Bom dia! Tentou usar o replace no SQL?

Comment: Não. Como posso usar?

Comment: campo = REPLACE(campo, 'TAG1', ' ')  - campo = nome do campo, tag1 = tag que será substituida e ' ', será trocado por vazio... creio que o problema ali seria o '\', ai você trocaria o tag1 por \ e deixa o proximo vazio.. Pode testar uma inserção manual pra ver...

Comment: Já tentou http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php e http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php?

Comment: Já tentei @Gerep, não funcionou.

Comment: @AndréBaill, vou tentar, obrigada

Comment: Poste o minimo de código por favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente usar esta função para converter a string para UTF-8:

`mb_convert_encoding($string, "UTF-8", mb_detect_encoding($string, "UTF-8, ISO-8859-1, ISO-8859-15", true));`